# Error getting the correct Python3 dependency

Tags: amazon-web-services, python, amazon-linux

I get this error when trying to install HTCondor on Amazon Linux 2 instance:

```
Error: Package: python3-condor-8.8.15-1.el7.x86_64 (htcondor-stable)
       Requires: libpython3.6m.so.1.0()(64bit)
```

I tried installing python 3.6 on my own (given that the one installed was 3.7) and in /usr/local/lib I have libpython3.6m.so.1.0. Is this the same as libpython3.6m.so.1.0()(64bit)?

Adding it to the LD Library Path (export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/) doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is helpful, but I've largely given up on Amazon Linux as it's too difficult to get some things working. I tend to use Ubuntu unless I know software will work on AL2.

Comment: Ok Tim, thanks for the suggestion, I will probably do the same. The installation went without problems on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering so the question can be closed off.

**TLDR:** use Ubuntu for the easiest experience on AWS EC2.

Amazon Linux 1 / 2 can make it quite difficult to install some software. I ran a web server on AL1 for years and had no end of problems, having to do basics like compiling Nginx myself, hassle installing everything.

When AL1 was reported "end of life" I moved to the latest Ubuntu LTS release, currently 20.04. It was much easier due to much better package management, much more help online as more people use it.

This isn't to say AL2 should never be used. It's likely highly optimized for EC2, so anyone who wants the best compatibility with AWS and best performance might find AL2 is worthwhile. Most enterprise servers only run one or two pieces of software so might be worth the time to get it working.